# Calculated column formula that always adds 1 to new item in List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, calculated-column-formula

What formula I can use in a column so the value in the field **always increases by 1 every time** a new item is created?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Where and how you want to use this calculated column formula? As detail description of the question will help others to understand your question

Comment: Alright, I'm trying to import and keep adding items with a number code that will start at 1000 for example. What I want is when an user creates a new item in the list the code number field changes to 1002, if another user creates an item it changes to 1003 and so on.

Comment: In calculated column, you can only get column related info for calculation, You can not get previous row data for calculation. Instead You can use event receiver i.e. "item adding" for that. It would be better for your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want a calculated column for it? You may use the default ID column, which will automatically get incremented by 1 whenever a new item is created.

Comment: Because I need to be able to set the number field with any number like 100 or 1000.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula like below

```
[ID]+StartingNumber
```

E.g.

```
[ID]+1000
```

It will automatically increase every time whenever new item created.

Comment: You should not us `ID` in calculated column, it will be blank when you update the list item

Comment: Yeah, then it is possible by ItemAdding Event receiver

Comment: Or with the Calculated Column+ Javascript hack: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160426/create-unique-number-with-listitem-id-and-today-age-in-calculated-column-for